# Building a list of dict from list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have the following tuple

```
[('A', 38, 132.0, 132.0), ('V', 22, 223.0, 223.0)]
```

I would like  to loop through it and create a dict that look like this:

```
[{'symbol': 'A', 'sumshares': 38, 'avgprice': 132.0, 'purchase_p': 132}, {'symbol': 'V', 'sumshares': 22, 'avgprice': 223.0, 'purchase_p': 223.0}]
```

Tried for few days to find the correct way to do this without success:(

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the code you have written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension. Why this works is that first the list comprehension destuctures each tuple in the original list and then the destructured variables (a, b, c, and d) are inserted into the dictionary.

```
original = [('A', 1, 2, 3), ('X', 3, 4, 5)]
dictionary = [{'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d} for a, b, c, d in original]
```

And with looping, you could use destructuring to get the values and append the list with dictionaries:

```
newlist = []

for row in original:
    a, b, c, d = row
    
    newlist.append({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d})

print(newlist)
```

Comment: Please read: [Answering Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/18116417)

Comment: Thanks @tiitinha great solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [('A', 38, 132.0, 132.0), ('V', 22, 223.0, 223.0)]
keys = ('symbol', 'sumshares', 'avgprice','purchase_p')
dlist = []

for l in lst:
    dlist.append(dict(zip(keys, l)))

print(dlist)
```

**output**

[{'symbol': 'A', 'sumshares': 38, 'avgprice': 132.0, 'purchase_p': 132.0}, {'symbol': 'V', 'sumshares': 22, 'avgprice': 223.0, 'purchase_p': 223.0}]

Answer (score 0):

```
data=[('A', 38, 132.0, 132.0), ('V', 22, 223.0, 223.0)]
keys=['symbol','sumshares','avgprice','purchase_p']
mydict=[dict(zip(keys,dat)) for dat in data ]

print(mydict)
```

output 
[{'symbol': 'A', 'sumshares': 38, 'avgprice': 132.0, 'purchase_p': 132.0}, {'symbol': 'V', 'sumshares': 22, 'avgprice': 223.0, 'purchase_p': 223.0}]